# SQL 'with' statement

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I have a syntax error here but can not find it. Any idea on this one?

```
WITH table_selection AS (SELECT device_name FROM devices WHERE device_id = 8),
column_names AS (SELECT column_name FROM device_parameters WHERE device_id =  8)
SELECT * FROM table_selection
```

The idea is that table_selection query get the name of the table, the column_names query get the column to read from that table,  and the SELECT will get all the values on column_names columns in table_selection.

The full error message is:

```
Exception: Error running query:
SQLQuery(query=; WITH table_selection AS (SELECT device_name FROM devices WHERE device_id = 5),
column_names AS (SELECT column_name FROM device_parameters WHERE device_id =  5)
SELECT * FROM table_selection
, database=Logging)@0ms
On: Data Tracker.Root Container.Table 2.data
    caused by GatewayException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; WITH table_selection AS (SELECT device_name FROM devices WHERE device_id = 5),' at line 1
    caused by MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '; WITH table_selection AS (SELECT device_name FROM devices WHERE device_id = 5),' at line 1

Ignition v7.9.5 (b2017111615)
Java: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_231
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? Please show us the entire error message.

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Hi I am using an industrial software called (Ignition). It manage any kind of data bases. 
I update the main post with the full error

Comment: does this version of `mySQL` support `CTE`?

Comment: What's the version of MySQL? 5.x does not support CTEs, while 8,x does.

Comment: Check to make sure the two component Selects run first.   If you still can’t get it to go, maybe try temporary tables - although it looks like a simple join would work.

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about the `;` at the beginning of the query. Have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 1):

WHY don't you try with `JOIN`

```
SELECT device_name,column_names 
FROM devices D JOIN device_parameters DP ON D.device_id = DP.device_id 
WHERE device_id = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the error message:

```
... near '; WITH ...
```

It is pointing at (or immediately before) the semi-colon.  I interpret that to mean that the client package does not know how to deal with two statements in one call.  (Most client APIs disallow such.)